# How to test whether an improper integral converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

To verify the improper integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}x\cdot\left | \sin (x^4)\cdot\sin x  \right |dx$ converges or diverges,I code

> ```
> Integrate[x*Abs[Sin[x^4]*Sin[x]], {x, 1, Infinity}]
> ```

then feedback is the expression of  $\int_{1}^{\infty}x\cdot\left | \sin (x^4)\cdot\sin x  \right |dx$.Is that means the improper integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}x\cdot\left | \sin (x^4)\cdot\sin x  \right |dx$ converges?

Comment: Obviously, the integral diverges. But it is surprising that the system does not give a message, and estimates the numerical value as `1.5408*10^147`

Comment: @AlexTrounev: Yes,I proved it diverges in the past  .But  after using mathematica to verify  my conclusion, I puzzled ! Thanks for your confirmation ! What's worng with it?

Comment: Not all cases have been studied and not all are entered into the database.

Comment: @AlexTrounev：Is there any better way to deal with this kind of problem？

Comment: Depends on what you want.

Comment: No, it doesn't mean it converges. It means it could not figure out the limit `Limit[x * f[x], x -> Infinity]` (I believe) or the series at infinity.

Comment: This is rather a math question than a Mathematica question: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018348/this-improper-integral-int-1-inftyx-sinx-sinx4dx-is-absolutely-con .

Comment: I should have been clearer, perhaps: `Limit[x * f[x], x -> Infinity]` returns `Interval[{0, Infinity}]`, meaning the function oscillates in this range as `x` goes to infinity.  Knowing just that is not enough to decide whether or not the integral converges (since the interval includes zero).

Comment: @user64494:Thanks for your reference.I didn't  know  there was the same question posted on  MS.But I  have a  completely independent analytic proof.However, in here, I  focus on  how to deal  with  this  problem applying mathematica and don't  care about the  rest.